# Como hacer para insertar una función de JavaScript de una alerta en un modal?

Tags: javascript, bootstrap, jsp

Al momento de presionar en el botón <kbd>Lo Quiero</kbd>, me sale ese cuadro de alerta modal, ese cuadro de alerta modal, es un JavaScript , el cual contiene el siguiente código:

```
function ConfirmDelete()
{
        
        var respuesta =confirm("Estas seguro que quieres adquirir este servicio?");
        if (respuesta == true) {
          return true;
           }
           else{
           return false;
           }
           }
```

Quería saber si puedo insertar esa función de js en este modal:

```
  <div class="modal fade" id="staticBackdrop" data-bs-backdrop="static" data-bs- 
   keyboard="false" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="staticBackdropLabel" aria-hidden="true">
   <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="staticBackdropLabel">Seguridad</h5>
                <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="mb-3 row">
                    <label for="inputdireccion" class="col col-form-label">¿Está seguro de realizar esta solicitud?</label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exito">Aceptar</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Volver</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

O en todo caso, en vez de que salga `localhost8080:dice`, cambiarlo por algún título aparte.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No puedes cambiar el título, esto es por motivos de seguridad. Siempre se mencionará el nombre del host (en tu caso localhost:8080) y luego el texto de la alerta.

Comment: Entonces , tendría que incluirlo en un modal para que se vea mejor estéticamente

Comment: En vez de abrir una alerta, usa el botón para abrir el modal. Adentro del modal agrega la opción de aceptar `true` o `false`

Comment: @Ricardo Así es Ricardo, tendrías que hacer un modal que salga encima de los demás elementos de tu página. Si usas `alert()` no vas a tener la personalización que andas buscando.